# How to Disable verification code emails when the user is not registered in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Azure B2C [Password-less sign-in with email verification](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email) sends the verification code to every email address (Even if no user is not registered in directory) .after entering OTP(Non-Registered user) B2C validated the code and says “E-mail address verified. You can now continue”.
Now when the users click “Continue” they get the error “An account could not be found for the provided user ID.” .This is where we got sure about non-registered user.

I found [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/pwd-reset-email-exists) solution but not getting results after updating my [current policy](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email).
I am including my updated [extension file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-7t_dgISZm-xkF4rIHsgs3uBw03vjz8V/edit) here .

Or if it has another approach on How to Disable verification code emails when the user is not registered in Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Your displayControl `emailVerificationControl` is referenced in `LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress-AcctExists` technical profile, but this technical profile is not part of your User Journey. Your signin step calls `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email`, but this is not defined in the file you have shared.

Your signin step needs to reference the `emailVerificationControl` displayControl for you to be utilizing the logic in the `pwd-reset-email-exists` sample.

Because of that, you are likely utilizing the old `email.verified` control instead in `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email`

Comment: @JasSuri What change exactly i need in User journey and in which order.

Comment: @JasSuri: I have done all changes but Its still not working.My Policy still sending mails to non registered users .also its sending mails for any character entered in email box.please suggest. here is my updated [TrustFrameworkExtensions](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-7t_dgISZm-xkF4rIHsgs3uBw03vjz8V/edit) file

Comment: @JasSuri kindly check my response in below thread ,as i wan not able to tag you there.thanks

Comment: @JasSuri It's working now, but for registered users,OTP verification is not working, its landing to next page by entering any random OTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```xml
<ClaimsExchange Id="SignIn-WithEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress-SignIn" />
```

To

```xml
<ClaimsExchange Id="SignIn-WithEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress-AcctExists" />
```

Now your user journey will call your technical profile which uses the `emailVerificationControl` display control which contains the logic to only send the email OTP if the account exists.

Comment: I have done all changes but Its still not working.My Policy still sending mails to non registered users .also its sending mails for any character entered in email box.please suggest.
here is my updated  [TrustFrameworkExtensions](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-7t_dgISZm-xkF4rIHsgs3uBw03vjz8V/edit)  file .

Comment: Are you sure about this? The sample does not return an error for an unknown email (for protection). Your last sentence makes me think you are not checking the inbox, only relying on the B2C UI.

Comment: if this is the case,well that creates more confusion to  user weather their account exists or not if its not returning an error on UI. 
Is it possible if the an unregistered user put email ,it simply returns an error that "account doesn't exist".

Comment: Well the opposite argument is that this can then be used to phish accounts. I prefer to prevent this. You can enable the error message in the AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-emailAddress technical profile metadata item: RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist.

Comment: @. JasSuri : It's working now, but for registered users,OTP verification is not working, its landing to next page by entering any random OTP.

Comment: Remove the precondition in the displayControl that applies to `<ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AadSspr-VerifyCode">`

Comment: Hi @JasSuri-MSFT, Can you advise more details about the steps to change the XML configurations? I am completely new to Azure AD B2C. We got this issue to be fixed for the mobile app and web app. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this policy (Link attached), and it works perfectly fine.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/pwd-reset-email-exists

The right approach is not to spam users by sending verifications emails to those who are not registered, and also not telling users that email is incorrect or the account doesn't exist because, that way attackers will find out if that is an incorrect email, and to prevent Brute-force attack on your login page.
So, therefore, you use can that policy to disable verification code emails, and also turn off the Raise Error flag (RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist=false):

[image]